# Hetzner issue: /etc/source.list is automatically overwritten when using Ansible

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I am trying to get ansible to work correctly on a Hetzner debian dedicated server. The problem is that hetzner automatically overwrites the /etc/sources.list file somehow.

I then get the following error when running `apt-get update`

```
E: The repository 'http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Something is clearly overwriting sources.list
At the top of the file, it even says

`# This file is managed remotely, all changes will be lost`

Any ideas?

```
# This file is managed remotely, all changes will be lost

# Original APT package sources gathered by Ansible
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages buster main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free

# Official Debian repositories
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
# deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free

# Debian Security repository
deb http://security.debian.org/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the message *"This file is managed remotely, all changes will be lost"* isn't from Ansible?
It seems unlikely that Hetzner would touch your *dedicated server*, unless you rented a managed system. If it were a VPS, that might be more plausible.

There is also no fatal error here, apt should work fine. The hetzner URLs seem broken, so apt is skipping them. The official links below should still be used regardless.

I think it's more likely you put those hetzner URLs in your ansible config and they are somehow wrong, so now you have errors fetching stuff from them.

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed a / at buster/updates

```
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages buster main
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages buster-updates main
deb http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/security buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian          buster         main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian          buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
```

works fine.